# Latex reported missing or unavailable character(s)

Tags: latexmk

Today when I compile the latex document, the log shows like this:

```
Overfull \hbox (25.45197pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 2479--2480
[]\T1/ptm/m/n/10 Performance Schema \TU/SongtiSCLight(0)/m/n/10 中 的 表 是 内 存 表，|
  不 使 用 磁 盘 存 储，|  在 \T1/ptm/m/n/10 datadir \TU/SongtiSCLight(0)/m/n/10 的 \T1/p
tm/m/n/10 per-for-mance_schema
[67] [68] [69] [70]
Chapter 2.
[71] [72] [73] [74] (./output/interview-question.ind)
(./output/interview-question.aux) )
(see the transcript file for additional information)
Output written on ./output/interview-question.xdv (84 pages, 1243756 bytes).
Transcript written on ./output/interview-question.log.
Latexmk: Examining 'output/interview-question.log'
=== TeX engine is 'XeTeX'
Latexmk: Index file 'output/interview-question.idx' was written
Latexmk: Log file says output to 'output/interview-question.xdv'
Latexmk: Summary of warnings from last run of *latex:
  =====Latex reported missing or unavailable character(s).
=====See log file for details.
Latexmk: Errors, so I did not complete making targets
Latexmk: Failure to make the files correctly
    ==> You will need to change a source file before I do another run <==
Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
  xelatex: Command for 'xelatex' gave return code 1
      Refer to 'output/interview-question.log' for details

=== Watching for updated files. Use ctrl/C to stop ...
```

the latexmk command could not recompile the document and refresh automatically, so I have to restart the `latexmk` compile command:

```
/Library/TeX/texbin/latexmk -pdfxe -pvc -xelatex -interaction=nonstopmode -output-directory="./output" "interview-question.tex"
```

what should I do to found the unavaliable characters? I found when I use the itemize code, it will show this error:

```
\begin{itemize}
    \item {Bundle Identifier}
    \item {App in App Store Connect (connected to the above Bundle Identifier)}
\end{itemize}
```

I have already add this package:

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
```

this is the minimal reproduce example, when change the itemize content, the latexmk could not recompile the document:

```
\documentclass[8pt]{book}

\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{ctex}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3cm,right=3cm, headsep=8pt]{geometry} % Page margins
\geometry{papersize={19cm,24cm}}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for including pictures
\graphicspath{{Pictures/}{Image/common/}} % Specifies the directory where pictures are stored
\usepackage{lipsum} % Inserts dummy text
\usepackage[ddmmyyyy]{datetime}
\usepackage{tikz} % Required for drawing custom shapes
\usepackage[english]{babel} % English language/hyphenation
\usepackage{enumitem} % Customize lists
\setlist{nolistsep} % Reduce spacing between bullet points and numbered lists
\usepackage{booktabs} % Required for nicer horizontal rules in tables
\usepackage{xcolor} % Required for specifying colors by name
\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{243,102,25} % Define the orange color used for highlighting throughout the book
\usepackage{avant} % Use the Avantgarde font for headings
%\usepackage{times} % Use the Times font for headings
\usepackage{mathptmx} % Use the Adobe Times Roman as the default text font together with math symbols from the Sym­bol, Chancery and Com­puter Modern fonts
\usepackage{microtype} % Slightly tweak font spacing for aesthetics
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
{\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}}
%\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=numeric]{biblatex}
%\defbibheading{bibempty}{}
\usepackage{calc} % 简单的计算功能
\usepackage{makeidx} % 创建索引
\makeindex % Tells LaTeX to create the files required for indexing
\usepackage{titletoc} % 目录操作
\usepackage[bookmarksopen,bookmarksdepth=4]{hyperref}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}


\makeatletter
\def\UrlAlphabet{%
    \do\a\do\b\do\c\do\d\do\e\do\f\do\g\do\h\do\i\do\j%
    \do\k\do\l\do\m\do\n\do\o\do\p\do\q\do\r\do\s\do\t%
    \do\u\do\v\do\w\do\x\do\y\do\z\do\A\do\B\do\C\do\D%
    \do\E\do\F\do\G\do\H\do\I\do\J\do\K\do\L\do\M\do\N%
    \do\O\do\P\do\Q\do\R\do\S\do\T\do\U\do\V\do\W\do\X%
    \do\Y\do\Z}
\def\UrlDigits{\do\1\do\2\do\3\do\4\do\5\do\6\do\7\do\8\do\9\do\0}
\g@addto@macro{\UrlBreaks}{\UrlOrds}
\g@addto@macro{\UrlBreaks}{\UrlAlphabet}
\g@addto@macro{\UrlBreaks}{\UrlDigits}
\makeatother


%When compile under liunx% 

%\setCJKmainfont{WenQuanYi Micro Hei} % 设置缺省中文字体

\contentsmargin{0cm} % Removes the default margin

\lstdefinelanguage{JavaScript}{
    keywords={typeof, new, true, false, catch, function, return, null, catch, switch, var, if, in, while, do, else, case, break},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}\bfseries,
    ndkeywords={class, export, boolean, throw, implements, import, this},
    ndkeywordstyle=\color{darkgray}\bfseries,
    identifierstyle=\color{black},
    sensitive=false,
    comment=[l]{//},
    morecomment=[s]{/*}{*/},
    commentstyle=\color{purple}\ttfamily,
    stringstyle=\color{red}\ttfamily,
    morestring=[b]',
    morestring=[b]"
}


\renewcommand\figurename{图}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}

%Set Code Format%
\lstloadlanguages{C, csh, make,python,Java,JavaScript}
\lstset{      
    alsolanguage= XML,  
    tabsize=4, %  
    frame=shadowbox,   
    commentstyle=\color{red!50!green!50!blue!50},%浅灰色的注释
    frameround=tttt,  
    rulesepcolor=\color{red!20!green!20!blue!20},%代码块边框为淡青色  
    keywordstyle=\color{blue!90}\bfseries, %代码关键字的颜色为蓝色，粗体  
    showstringspaces=false,  
    stringstyle=\ttfamily,  
    keepspaces=true,  
    breakindent=22pt, 
    breaklines=true, 
    numbers=left,  
    stepnumber=1, 
    %numberstyle=\tiny,  
    numberstyle={\color[RGB]{0,192,192}\tiny},%设置行号的大小，大小有tiny,scriptsize,footnotesize,small,normalsize,large等  
    numbersep=8pt,  
    basicstyle=\ttfamily, 
    showspaces=false, 
    escapechar=`,
    flexiblecolumns=true,  
    breaklines=true,  
    breakautoindent=true,  
    breakindent=4em,       
    aboveskip=1em,  
    tabsize=4,  
    showstringspaces=false,  
    backgroundcolor=\color[RGB]{245,245,244},    
    %backgroundcolor=\color[rgb]{0.91,0.91,0.91}    %添加背景色  
    escapeinside={``}{\_},  %在``里显示中文  
    %% added by http://bbs.ctex.org/viewthread.php?tid=53451  
    fontadjust,  
    captionpos=t,  
    framextopmargin=2pt,
    framexbottommargin=2pt,
    abovecaptionskip=-3pt,
    belowcaptionskip=3pt,  
    xleftmargin=1em,
    xrightmargin=1em,  
    texcl=true
}

%%%\titlecontents{part}[0cm]{\addvspace{20pt}\centering\large\sffamily}{}{}{}

\titlecontents{chapter}[1.25cm] % Indentation
{\addvspace{12pt}\large\sffamily\bfseries} % Spacing and font options for chapters
{\color{ocre!60}\contentslabel[\Large\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}\color{ocre}} % Chapter number
{\color{ocre}}  
{\color{ocre!60}\normalsize\;\titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage} % Page number

% Section text styling
\titlecontents{section}[1.25cm] % Indentation
{\addvspace{3pt}\sffamily\bfseries} % Spacing and font options for sections
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}} % Section number
{}
{\hfill\color{black}\thecontentspage} % Page number
[]

% Subsection text styling
\titlecontents{subsection}[1.25cm] % Indentation
{\addvspace{1pt}\sffamily\small} % Spacing and font options for subsections
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}} % Subsection number
{}
{\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage} % Page number
[]

% List of figures
\titlecontents{figure}[0em]
{\addvspace{-5pt}\sffamily}
{\thecontentslabel\hspace*{1em}}
{}
{\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage}
[]

% List of tables
\titlecontents{table}[0em]
{\addvspace{-5pt}\sffamily}
{\thecontentslabel\hspace*{1em}}
{}
{\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage}
[]

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   MINI TABLE OF CONTENTS IN PART HEADS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% Chapter text styling
\titlecontents{lchapter}[0em] % Indenting
{\addvspace{15pt}\large\sffamily\bfseries} % Spacing and font options for chapters
{\color{ocre}\contentslabel[\Large\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}\color{ocre}} % Chapter number
{}  
{\color{ocre}\normalsize\sffamily\bfseries\;\titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage} % Page number

% Section text styling
\titlecontents{lsection}[0em] % Indenting
{\sffamily\small} % Spacing and font options for sections
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}} % Section number
{}
{}

% Subsection text styling
\titlecontents{lsubsection}[.5em] % Indentation
{\normalfont\footnotesize\sffamily} % Font settings
{}
{}
{}

%------
%   PAGE HEADERS
%-------

\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Required for header and footer configuration

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\sffamily\normalsize\bfseries\chaptername\ \thechapter.\ #1}{}} % Chapter text font settings
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\sffamily\normalsize\thesection\hspace{5pt}#1}{}} % Section text font settings
\fancyhf{} \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\sffamily\normalsize\thepage} % Font setting for the page number in the header
\fancyhead[LO]{\rightmark} % Print the nearest section name on the left side of odd pages
\fancyhead[RE]{\leftmark} % Print the current chapter name on the right side of even pages
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt} % Width of the rule under the header
\addtolength{\headheight}{2.5pt} % Increase the spacing around the header slightly
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt} % Removes the rule in the footer
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhead{}\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}} % Style for when a plain pagestyle is specified

% Removes the header from odd empty pages at the end of chapters
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{
    \clearpage\ifodd\c@page\else
    \hbox{}
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \newpage
    \fi}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   THEOREM STYLES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm} % For math equations, theorems, symbols, etc

\newcommand{\intoo}[2]{\mathopen{]}#1\,;#2\mathclose{[}}
\newcommand{\ud}{\mathop{\mathrm{{}d}}\mathopen{}}
\newcommand{\intff}[2]{\mathopen{[}#1\,;#2\mathclose{]}}
\newtheorem{notation}{Notation}[chapter]

% Boxed/framed environments
\newtheoremstyle{ocrenumbox}% % Theorem style name
{0pt}% Space above
{0pt}% Space below
{\normalfont}% % Body font
{}% Indent amount
{\small\bf\sffamily\color{ocre}}% % Theorem head font
{\;}% Punctuation after theorem head
{0.25em}% Space after theorem head
{\small\sffamily\color{ocre}\thmname{#1}\nobreakspace\thmnumber{\@ifnotempty{#1}{}\@upn{#2}}% Theorem text (e.g. Theorem 2.1)
    \thmnote{\nobreakspace\the\thm@notefont\sffamily\bfseries\color{black}---\nobreakspace#3.}} % Optional theorem note
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\blacksquare$}% Optional qed square

\newtheoremstyle{blacknumex}% Theorem style name
{5pt}% Space above
{5pt}% Space below
{\normalfont}% Body font
{} % Indent amount
{\small\bf\sffamily}% Theorem head font
{\;}% Punctuation after theorem head
{0.25em}% Space after theorem head
{\small\sffamily{\tiny\ensuremath{\blacksquare}}\nobreakspace\thmname{#1}\nobreakspace\thmnumber{\@ifnotempty{#1}{}\@upn{#2}}% Theorem text (e.g. Theorem 2.1)
    \thmnote{\nobreakspace\the\thm@notefont\sffamily\bfseries---\nobreakspace#3.}}% Optional theorem note

\newtheoremstyle{blacknumbox} % Theorem style name
{0pt}% Space above
{0pt}% Space below
{\normalfont}% Body font
{}% Indent amount
{\small\bf\sffamily}% Theorem head font
{\;}% Punctuation after theorem head
{0.25em}% Space after theorem head
{\small\sffamily\thmname{#1}\nobreakspace\thmnumber{\@ifnotempty{#1}{}\@upn{#2}}% Theorem text (e.g. Theorem 2.1)
    \thmnote{\nobreakspace\the\thm@notefont\sffamily\bfseries---\nobreakspace#3.}}% Optional theorem note

% Non-boxed/non-framed environments
\newtheoremstyle{ocrenum}% % Theorem style name
{5pt}% Space above
{5pt}% Space below
{\normalfont}% % Body font
{}% Indent amount
{\small\bf\sffamily\color{ocre}}% % Theorem head font
{\;}% Punctuation after theorem head
{0.25em}% Space after theorem head
{\small\sffamily\color{ocre}\thmname{#1}\nobreakspace\thmnumber{\@ifnotempty{#1}{}\@upn{#2}}% Theorem text (e.g. Theorem 2.1)
    \thmnote{\nobreakspace\the\thm@notefont\sffamily\bfseries\color{black}---\nobreakspace#3.}} % Optional theorem note
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\blacksquare$}% Optional qed square
\makeatother 

% Defines the theorem text style for each type of theorem to one of the three styles above
\newcounter{dummy} 
\numberwithin{dummy}{section}
\theoremstyle{ocrenumbox}
\newtheorem{theoremeT}[dummy]{Theorem}
\newtheorem{problem}{Problem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{exerciseT}{Exercise}[chapter]
\theoremstyle{blacknumex}
\newtheorem{exampleT}{Example}[chapter]
\theoremstyle{blacknumbox}
\newtheorem{vocabulary}{Vocabulary}[chapter]
\newtheorem{definitionT}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{corollaryT}[dummy]{Corollary}
\theoremstyle{ocrenum}
\newtheorem{proposition}[dummy]{Proposition}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   DEFINITION OF COLORED BOXES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\RequirePackage[framemethod=default]{mdframed} % Required for creating the theorem, definition, exercise and corollary boxes

% Theorem box
\newmdenv[skipabove=7pt,
skipbelow=7pt,
backgroundcolor=black!5,
linecolor=ocre,
innerleftmargin=5pt,
innerrightmargin=5pt,
innertopmargin=5pt,
leftmargin=0cm,
rightmargin=0cm,
innerbottommargin=5pt]{tBox}

% Exercise box    
\newmdenv[skipabove=7pt,
skipbelow=7pt,
rightline=false,
leftline=true,
topline=false,
bottomline=false,
backgroundcolor=ocre!10,
linecolor=ocre,
innerleftmargin=5pt,
innerrightmargin=5pt,
innertopmargin=5pt,
innerbottommargin=5pt,
leftmargin=0cm,
rightmargin=0cm,
linewidth=4pt]{eBox}    

% Definition box
\newmdenv[skipabove=7pt,
skipbelow=7pt,
rightline=false,
leftline=true,
topline=false,
bottomline=false,
linecolor=ocre,
innerleftmargin=5pt,
innerrightmargin=5pt,
innertopmargin=0pt,
leftmargin=0cm,
rightmargin=0cm,
linewidth=4pt,
innerbottommargin=0pt]{dBox}    

% Corollary box
\newmdenv[skipabove=7pt,
skipbelow=7pt,
rightline=false,
leftline=true,
topline=false,
bottomline=false,
linecolor=gray,
backgroundcolor=black!5,
innerleftmargin=5pt,
innerrightmargin=5pt,
innertopmargin=5pt,
leftmargin=0cm,
rightmargin=0cm,
linewidth=4pt,
innerbottommargin=5pt]{cBox}

% Creates an environment for each type of theorem and assigns it a theorem text style from the "Theorem Styles" section above and a colored box from above
\newenvironment{theorem}{\begin{tBox}\begin{theoremeT}}{\end{theoremeT}\end{tBox}}
\newenvironment{exercise}{\begin{eBox}\begin{exerciseT}}{\hfill{\color{ocre}\tiny\ensuremath{\blacksquare}}\end{exerciseT}\end{eBox}}                 
\newenvironment{definition}{\begin{dBox}\begin{definitionT}}{\end{definitionT}\end{dBox}}   
\newenvironment{example}{\begin{exampleT}}{\hfill{\tiny\ensuremath{\blacksquare}}\end{exampleT}}        
\newenvironment{corollary}{\begin{cBox}\begin{corollaryT}}{\end{corollaryT}\end{cBox}}  

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   REMARK ENVIRONMENT
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newenvironment{remark}{\par\vspace{10pt}\small % Vertical white space above the remark and smaller font size
    \begin{list}{}{
            \leftmargin=35pt % Indentation on the left
            \rightmargin=25pt}\item\ignorespaces % Indentation on the right
        \makebox[-2.5pt]{\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
            \node[draw=ocre!60,line width=1pt,circle,fill=ocre!25,font=\sffamily\bfseries,inner sep=2pt,outer sep=0pt] at (-15pt,0pt){\textcolor{ocre}{R}};\end{tikzpicture}} % Orange R in a circle
        \advance\baselineskip -1pt}{\end{list}\vskip5pt} % Tighter line spacing and white space after remark

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   SECTION NUMBERING IN THE MARGIN
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{\llap{\textcolor{ocre}{\csname the#1\endcsname}\hspace{1em}}}                    
\renewcommand{\section}{\@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}
    {-4ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.4ex}
    {1ex \@plus.2ex }
    {\normalfont\large\sffamily\bfseries}}
\renewcommand{\subsection}{\@startsection {subsection}{2}{\z@}
    {-3ex \@plus -0.1ex \@minus -.4ex}
    {0.5ex \@plus.2ex }
    {\normalfont\sffamily\bfseries}}
\renewcommand{\subsubsection}{\@startsection {subsubsection}{3}{\z@}
    {-2ex \@plus -0.1ex \@minus -.2ex}
    {.2ex \@plus.2ex }
    {\normalfont\small\sffamily\bfseries}}                        
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}
    {-2ex \@plus-.2ex \@minus .2ex}
    {.1ex}
    {\normalfont\small\sffamily\bfseries}}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PART HEADINGS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% numbered part in the table of contents
\newcommand{\@mypartnumtocformat}[2]{%
    \setlength\fboxsep{0pt}%
    \noindent\colorbox{ocre!20}{\strut\parbox[c][.7cm]{\ecart}{\color{ocre!70}\Large\sffamily\bfseries\centering#1}}\hskip\esp\colorbox{ocre!40}{\strut\parbox[c][.7cm]{\linewidth-\ecart-\esp}{\Large\sffamily\centering#2}}}%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% unnumbered part in the table of contents
\newcommand{\@myparttocformat}[1]{%
    \setlength\fboxsep{0pt}%
    \noindent\colorbox{ocre!40}{\strut\parbox[c][.7cm]{\linewidth}{\Large\sffamily\centering#1}}}%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newlength\esp
\setlength\esp{4pt}
\newlength\ecart
\setlength\ecart{1.2cm-\esp}
\newcommand{\thepartimage}{}%
\newcommand{\partimage}[1]{\renewcommand{\thepartimage}{#1}}%

\def\@part[#1]#2{%
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax%
    \refstepcounter{part}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\texorpdfstring{\protect\@mypartnumtocformat{\thepart}{#1}}{\partname~\thepart\ ---\ #1}}
    \else%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\texorpdfstring{\protect\@myparttocformat{#1}}{#1}}%
    \fi%
    \startcontents%
    \markboth{}{}%
    {\thispagestyle{empty}%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
        \node at (current page.north west){\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%   
            \fill[ocre!20](0cm,0cm) rectangle (\paperwidth,-\paperheight);
            \node[anchor=north] at (4cm,-3.25cm){\color{ocre!40}\fontsize{220}{100}\sffamily\bfseries\@Roman\c@part}; 
            \node[anchor=south east] at (\paperwidth-1cm,-\paperheight+1cm){\parbox[t][][t]{8.5cm}{
                    \printcontents{l}{0}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}%
            }};
            \node[anchor=north east] at (\paperwidth-1.5cm,-3.25cm){\parbox[t][][t]{15cm}{\strut\raggedleft\color{white}\fontsize{30}{30}\sffamily\bfseries#2}};\end{tikzpicture}};
    \end{tikzpicture}}
\@endpart}

\def\@spart#1{%
\startcontents%
\phantomsection
{\thispagestyle{empty}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
    \node at (current page.north west){\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%   
        \fill[ocre!20](0cm,0cm) rectangle (\paperwidth,-\paperheight);
        \node[anchor=north east] at (\paperwidth-1.5cm,-3.25cm){\parbox[t][][t]{15cm}{\strut\raggedleft\color{white}\fontsize{30}{30}\sffamily\bfseries#1}};
        \end{tikzpicture}};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\texorpdfstring{%
    \setlength\fboxsep{0pt}%
    \noindent\protect\colorbox{ocre!40}{\strut\protect\parbox[c][.7cm]{\linewidth}{\Large\sffamily\protect\centering #1\quad\mbox{}}}}{#1}}%
\@endpart}
\def\@endpart{\vfil\newpage
\if@twoside
\if@openright
\null
\thispagestyle{empty}%
\newpage
\fi
\fi
\if@tempswa
\twocolumn
\fi}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CHAPTER HEADINGS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% A switch to conditionally include a picture, implemented by  Christian Hupfer
\newif\ifusechapterimage
\usechapterimagetrue
\newcommand{\thechapterimage}{}%
\newcommand{\chapterimage}[1]{\ifusechapterimage\renewcommand{\thechapterimage}{#1}\fi}%
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
{\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
\if@mainmatter
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node at (current page.north west)
{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt] at (0,0) {\ifusechapterimage\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{\thechapterimage}\fi};
    \draw[anchor=west] (\Gm@lmargin,-9cm) node [line width=2pt,rounded corners=15pt,draw=ocre,fill=white,fill opacity=0.5,inner sep=15pt]{\strut\makebox[22cm]{}};
    \draw[anchor=west] (\Gm@lmargin+.3cm,-9cm) node {\huge\sffamily\bfseries\color{black}\thechapter. #1\strut};
    \end{tikzpicture}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\else
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node at (current page.north west)
{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt] at (0,0) {\ifusechapterimage\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{\thechapterimage}\fi};
\draw[anchor=west] (\Gm@lmargin,-9cm) node [line width=2pt,rounded corners=15pt,draw=ocre,fill=white,fill opacity=0.5,inner sep=15pt]{\strut\makebox[22cm]{}};
\draw[anchor=west] (\Gm@lmargin+.3cm,-9cm) node {\huge\sffamily\bfseries\color{black}#1\strut};
\end{tikzpicture}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\fi\fi\par\vspace*{270\p@}}}

%-------------------------------------------

\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node at (current page.north west)
{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt] at (0,0) {\ifusechapterimage\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{\thechapterimage}\fi};
\draw[anchor=west] (\Gm@lmargin,-9cm) node [line width=2pt,rounded corners=15pt,draw=ocre,fill=white,fill opacity=0.5,inner sep=15pt]{\strut\makebox[22cm]{}};
\draw[anchor=west] (\Gm@lmargin+.3cm,-9cm) node {\huge\sffamily\bfseries\color{black}#1\strut};
\end{tikzpicture}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\par\vspace*{270\p@}}
\makeatother

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   HYPERLINKS IN THE DOCUMENTS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{hidelinks,backref=true,pagebackref=true,hyperindex=true,colorlinks=false,breaklinks=true,urlcolor= ocre,bookmarks=true,bookmarksopen=false,pdftitle={Title},pdfauthor={Author}}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\bookmarksetup{
open,
numbered,
addtohook={%
\ifnum\bookmarkget{level}=0 % chapter
\bookmarksetup{bold}%
\fi
\ifnum\bookmarkget{level}=-1 % part
\bookmarksetup{color=ocre,bold}%
\fi
}
}

%\addbibresource{Bronvermelding.bib} 

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\coordinate [below=12cm] (midpoint) at (current page.north);
\node at (current page.north west)
{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt] at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{background}}; % Background image
\draw[anchor=north] (midpoint) node [fill=ocre!30!white,fill opacity=0.6,text opacity=1,inner sep=1cm]{\Huge\centering\bfseries\sffamily\parbox[c][][t]{\paperwidth}{\centering 面试记录 \\[15pt] % Book title
{\Large 卷一}\\[20pt] % Subtitle
{\large 蒋小强}}}; % Author name
\end{tikzpicture}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\vfill
\endgroup


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   BLANK PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newpage
~\vfill
\thispagestyle{empty}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   COPYRIGHT PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newpage
~\vfill
\thispagestyle{empty}

%\noindent Copyright \textcopyright\ 2017 Xiaoqiang Jiang\\ % Copyright notice

\noindent \textsc{Edited by Xiaoqiang Jiang}\\ % Publisher

\noindent \textsc{\url{http://jiangxiaoqiang.github.com/}}\\

\noindent All Rights Reserved.\\ % License information

\noindent \textit{Version \currenttime, \today} % Printing/edition date


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TABLE OF CONTENTS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%\usechapterimagefalse % If you don't want to include a chapter image, use this to toggle images off - it can be enabled later with \usechapterimagetrue

\chapterimage{chapterhead1.pdf} % Table of contents heading image

\pagestyle{empty} % No headers

\tableofcontents % Print the table of contents itself

\cleardoublepage % Forces the first chapter to start on an odd page so it's on the right

\pagestyle{fancy} % Print headers again

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   BLANK PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



面试问题集合。


\mainmatter

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% PART
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


\part{第一部}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CHAPTER 1
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\chapterimage{chapterhead2.pdf} % Chapter heading image

%\subfile{./tech/tech.tex}

\begin{itemize}
    \item {Bundle Identifier}
    \item {App in App Store Connect (connected to the above Bundle Identifier)}
\end{itemize}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   BIBLIOGRAPHY
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\chapter*{Bibliography}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textcolor{ocre}{Bibliography}}
\section*{Books}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Books}
%\printbibliography[heading=bibempty,type=book]
\section*{Articles}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Articles}
%\printbibliography[heading=bibempty,type=article]

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   INDEX
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.75cm}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textcolor{ocre}{Index}}
\printindex

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

Comment: "See log file for details"?

Comment: Have you looked at the file `interview-question.log` in the `output` (sub)directory?

Comment: you have not shown the log or any messages relating to missing characters. Note the part of the log that you did show `[]\T1/ptm/m/n/10 Performance Schema \TU/SongtiSCLight`  shows that you are using T1 encoding in XeLaTeX, this  is usually wrong and will lead to incorrect hyphnation, never use `\usepackag[T1]{fontenc}` in latex just use the default TU (Unicode) encoding.

Comment: I checked the source file and already add this `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` @DavidCarlisle

Comment: if it has that, the file is not suitable for use with xelatex, it should only be used with pdflatex.

Comment: you still have no shown the latex log file, that is the ouput from latexmk, which says to look in the log file for information: `See log file for details.` so currently you have not provided an example we can test and not shown the error that you get, so it is hard to help.